# can we write a file to appication directory in FLEX?

Tags: apache-flex

how to write a file to File.applicationDirectory in flex. i am getting security  filewrite resource error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you delete a file in the application directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760893/how-can-you-delete-a-file-in-the-application-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use File.applicationDirectory in pure flex , it is ment to be used only in air applications.
in flex you can use Filereference.save() which opens a dialog box where user can select the folder to save the file in.