# Is it possible to change the application descriptor file in air?

Tags: air

I would like to have an option in the application: gpu [on/off], but it can't be set in runtime (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d719af412b2b394529-8000.html).
So, if there is an ability to change or substitute application.xml I would change it and restart the application.

I found this topic [How can you delete a file in the application directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760893/how-can-you-delete-a-file-in-the-application-directory), but the suggested solution doesn't work.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: which suggested solution doesnt work? and how - error message? does nothing?

Comment: This doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12861989/2061081. I get the SecurityError: fileWriteResource
          at flash.filesystem::FileStream/open().
 
Obviously, "app:/" location doesn't permit writing.