# FLEX MOBILE: Can't read images "saved" on local filesystem on my android tablet

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, local-storage, flex-mobile

I'm downloading some images into my application so they can be displayed without consuming any  bandwidth. The code I'm using to store the images on my android device is the following:

```
        var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);
        if (file.exists)
        {
            file.deleteFile(); //delete it if exists
        }                                   

        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();           
        fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);          
        fileStream.writeBytes(data, 0, data.length);            
        fileStream.close();     
        var showLocalPath:String = file.nativePath;
```

To display the images I'm using the following two examples:

```
<s:BitmapImage id="iconStateImage" source="{appContext.CurrentState.IconImage}"/>
<s:Image id="backgroundStateImage" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" source="{File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(appContext.CurrentState.BackgroundImage)}"/>
```

Both `appContext.CurrentState.IconImage` and `appContext.CurrentState.BackgroundImage` have the same path of the former `fileName`. Even though I'm trying to load the images with full path (second case) or with a short path (first one), I'm not able to display it.

I already set the WRITTING permissions on the project.

Can some help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Sebastián

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.applicationDirectory` is read-only; you'll want to use `File.applicationStorageDirectory` instead.

See also [How can you delete a file in the application directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760893/how-can-you-delete-a-file-in-the-application-directory) and the [Flex File documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html).

Then add "app-storage:/" before the image path:

`<s:Image id="backgroundStateImage" source="app-storage:/{appContext.CurrentState.BackgroundImage}"/>`

Comment: Thanks Brian. That's only half of the way though. I  'usedapplicationStorageDirectory' as you said but I also needed to add  "app-storage:/" before the image path. Next is the example:
'<s:Image id="backgroundStateImage"
 source="app-storage:/{appContext.CurrentState.BackgroundImage}"/>'
Please add that to your answer so I can mark it as correct.